# Add Custom Term to RSS Feed Titles

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rss

I've got a [custom blog](https://www.alltimelines.com/blog/) that I hired someone to create. It displays posts, but also specific pages and a custom post type, as long as they are marked under a certain taxonomy ('Status').

As you can see in the first few entries, it's coordinated so that the title displays the term first, then the title of the page/cpt, like "Review: Justice League" aka "[META TERM]: [TITLE]" but what I really want is for the RSS feed to have the same format. And neither I nor the guy I hired can figure out how to do that.

In other words, how can I get the RSS item titles to include the meta term name in front of the title itself?

Comment: I see in the rss to work as you want `<title>Ultimate Fandom Timeline: The Origin of Magic</title>`

Comment: In that case, it's the full post title. "Ultimate Fandom Timeline" is not a taxonomy term.

Comment: Take a look in this filter `apply_filters( 'the_title_rss', string $title )` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title_rss/

Comment: We tried that. We weren't able to find an option to add a condition based on post type. How would you code that?